# regiona setting Encoding problems

Tags: c#, character-encoding, ascii, regional-settings

I have a config file in xml format for my applications. The xml file strats with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

In this file I have a setting that contains "i" character (73 ASCII code). If I change my regional setting to Turkish and location to Turkey then when I get the setting from the config file the character does not have 73 ASCII code anymore, it has 196 176.
How can I convert the settign so I can get to "i" with 73 ascii code not the 196 176 one.
Thank you,
Bogdan

here is some code..

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(configFilePath);
....
node = perentNode.SelectNodes("MySetting");
string mysetting = node[0].InnerText;
```

Comment: How do you read that config data ? Can provide some code sample ?

Comment: The table here: http://www.ascii.cl/ claims ASCII with a value of 73 is actually a capital I.  The reason it is converting the value is because your changing the region setting.  The solution force the regional setting within the code.

Comment: @Ramhound can you point me to the right direction... how exactly should I force the regional setting within the code only in the portion where I use the config file setting?

Comment: The xml is encoded in utf8.  That does *not* leave any room to interpret its character codes differently.  Whatever is going wrong is going wrong after you've retrieved the element text.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem doing

var oldSetting = Application.CurrentCulture;
Application.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
..myjob
Application.CurrentCulture = oldSetting;